# how to import binance data by Import JSON into google sheets?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, binance

I have got import JSON script:
https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164

and paste it in google apps script inside google sheets and I want to import this Json:
https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/ticker/24hr

But I do not know how to paste in importJSON formula in google sheets, when I put this link into the formula, it does not fetch any data? what is wrong? what do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete solution https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DN0Gfim0LC098zVgrUpt2crPWUn4pWfZnCpuuL1ZiMs/copy with all data and a selection in a portfolio. You can check or uncheck to update. You can also put a trigger to get the sheet always updated.

```
// Mike Steelson
let resultat = [];
function getDataJSON(url,xpath){
  try{
    var json = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())
    var list = xpath.join().split(",")
    if (json.length){json.forEach(function(elem){getData(elem,list)})} else {getData(json,list)}
    return resultat
  }
  catch(e) {
    return ('No data !');
  }
}
function getData(elem,list){
  var prov=[]
  list.forEach(function(path){prov.push(elem[path])})
  resultat.push(prov)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using an awesome Google App Script by Diego Calero.

Here is the link for the GitHub repo: https://github.com/diegomanuel/binance-to-google-sheets

This has many features implemented ready to use directly, we just need to enter our API details to get User & Account related info, Public data is available right away just need to use the custom function name written in the script.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30768969)